# Basic question on the probability function and the probability distribution function

Tags: probability, functions

I have a question on the probability function. In my book it says that if A and B are mutually exclusive events $P(A∪B)=P(A) + P(B)$. Then when it starts talking about the probability distribution function it says that  $P(a< X)=P(X≤b)-P(X≤a)$.
If I get things right this is because $-P(X≤a)=P(a< X)$ and then  $P(X≤b)-P(X≤a)= P(X≤b)+P(a< X)$.

But here comes what confuses me: Is it the fact that $P(A∪B)=P(A) + P(B) ($if $A∩B=Ø)$ that implies that $P(X≤b)+P(a< X)= P(a< X≤b)$ ?
I understand $a< X≤b$ as being the intersection of $X≤b$ and $a< X$ and not the union?

In short my question is: Why is $P(a< X≤b)=P(X≤b)-P(X≤a)$?

Can someone help me sort this out?

Kind regards,

Comment: $-P(X≤a)\neq P(a< X)=1-P(X≤a) $

Comment: Thank you for pinting it out! I still find it difficult to put it together though.

Answer (score 2):

Assume $a<b$

The event $X\le b$ can be divided into the events $a<X\le b$ and the event
$X\le a$. These events cannot occur simultaneously, so we have

$$P(a<X\le b)+P(X\le a)=P(X\le b)$$

Answer (score 1):

Let's try to understand the events

Consider

$\begin{align}a< X \le b &= \{x: a<x\le b\}\\ X\le b &=\{x: x\le b\}\\ X\le a &=\{x: x\le a\} \end{align}$

So simply $a< x \le b = (x\le b)-(x\le a)$

That is why $P(a< X \le b)=P(X \le b)-P(X \le a)$